# cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable package views

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

Im using **cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable package** to get page views. When I check out the documentation, I don't see a method where I can only get views for a single date. It uses **Period** and **Carbon** to get dates in a particular period so the (since and upTo) functions.

Any fix or alternative package to get page views.

I am trying to create a analytics page.

```
  public function pastDateViewsChart(){
$days = [];
$view_count = [];
foreach($this->views as $v){
  //get views for the past 28 days
  if($v->viewed_at >= Carbon::create("28 days ago")){
    if(!in_array(Carbon::parse($v->viewed_at)->format('Y-m-d'),$days,true))
  array_push($days, Carbon::parse($v->viewed_at)->format('Y-m-d'));
  }
}

//get views for each day
  $count = views($this)
  ->period(Period::upto(Carbon::parse($days[0])))
  ->count();

  array_push($view_count,$count);




return $view_count;
}
```

Comment: Use period with startdate and end date is a same day.

Comment: I tried that, even with the example on the documentation and it returns 0. Do you have any example that could show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not limited to since and upto, Period has (as per what I can see there https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable/blob/master/src/Support/Period.php) a create method that can take any date as start and end:

```php
->period(Period::create(
  Carbon::parse($days[0])->startOfDay(),
  Carbon::parse($days[0])->endOfDay()
))
```